# Windows to Unix - something lost in the translation

Tags: javascript, windows, unix, raspberry-pi

I've finished a webpage that loads csv data and creates a line chart using d3 and c3. The data file is in a subdirectory as are the other resource files. I copied everything to the '/var/www/html' directory on a Raspberry Pi 3B/Raspbian(Debian linux derivative).
The directory references in the html/javascript are './data2min/11-21-2016.csv' for the datafile, and './resources/C3.js' and './resources/C3.css' for resource files.
The chart background draws perfectly, but the data is not plotted. I tried running the example csv datafile through a DOS-to-UNIX converter with no luck. The javascript is working. The datafile doesn't seem to be loading.
Any ideas?

Comment: This question is too broad and this isn't the right Stack Exchange site for this question, along with that there isn't enough information to answer this. If the data file isn't loading then you are not accessing the correct directory, check the console in your browser.

Comment: The problem may be in the directory notation. "./", "../", "/././"

Comment: Since the chart draws perfectly, the resource files:'c3.js' and 'c3.css' and 'd3.min.js' are being accessed in the './resource' subdirectory. Since the notation I've used is the same for all,'./subdirectory',  I can assume the csv's directory('data2min') is being accessed. I don't believe I'm familiar with the concept of a browser having a console. If you mean the 'inspect' function some browsers have, the Linux Epiphany browser does not, to my knowledge. Otherwise, I don't see how opening a console window would help.

Comment: There may not be enough information to solve the problem. I may not know what information is necessary to solve the problem, if I did, I would solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the csv datafile through a DOS-to-Unix converter. No apparent success. I rebooted the next day, tried placing the example in the same directory as the html, edited, and that worked. I retried the original sub-directory configuration, html edited, and that worked. I can only imagine rebooting, next day, had some effect.